# How to automate a 'triple-click' using Java & Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, click

I'm automating tests that deal with text, and I need to be able to select an entire paragraph.  In order to do this (at this point) I need to automate a triple click.  Any idea how to do that?

This is what I've attempted so far, neither works:

```
action.click().click().click().perform();

//and...

for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    action.click().perform();
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you are trying to highlight the text over a paragraph of text?  I don't know if this is possible with selenium, because the drivers don't actually simulate a mouse.  That said, if you want to get the text of a paragraph, wouldn't calling `elem.getText()` work?

Comment: Good question. No that wouldn't work in this case because I'm working within an HTML5 Canvas. :-S

Comment: Doesn't matter, you should be able to use a JavaScriptExecutor to get the text.

Comment: I don't know how you plan on getting text that's in a canvas like this: http://www.rgraph.net/blog/2013/april/an-example-of-the-html5-canvas-text-function.html  It's practically an image.

Comment: When the page is loaded the cursor is active inside the canvas. I am able automate the cursor movement by sending arrow keys.

Comment: How about just coding a triple-click in general, not within an HTML 5 Canvas?

Comment: @urbanaut I know I am late to this but did you get any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while, but I believe this was the solution that ended up working for me:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public void tripleClick() {
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement cursor = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'rCursor')]"));
    int count = 3;

    while(count>0){
        action.click(cursor).perform();
        count -= 1;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey i know it has been 3 years since you posted this. But do you have any way to translate this script to python?