# Triple click using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, dom-events

This question is similar to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363633/how-to-automate-a-triple-click-using-java-selenium). However in that case it seems that the poster's ultimate purpose was actually to select a paragraph of text, and they were able to find a work-around which did not involve clicking.

Like the user in the above question I initially thought that it would be possible to simulate a triple-click by calling the click method three times.

```
new Actions(driver)
  .moveToElement(svgElement, posX, posY)                     
  .click()
  .click()
  .click()
  .perform()
```

However, this doesn't work as the my javascript code checks the the `detail` attribute of the `UIEvent` instance, and this is always `1` for each call to `click`. Thus the following snippet:

```
function clickHandler (event) {
    if (event.detail == 1) {
        singleClickHandler() 
    }
    if (event.detail == 2) {
        doubleClickHandler() 
    }
    if (event.detail == 3) {
        tripleClickHandler() 
    }
```

causes `singleClickHandler` to be called three times when called via Selenium, whereas each of `singleClickHandler`, `doubleClickHandler`, and `tripleClickHandler` is called once when this is exercised manually via the browser (Firefox).

How do I cause a click event with `detail` equal to 3 to be triggered via selenium?

Comment: i can see there is not option in Actions class as like double click. Have you checked trying Robot class?

Comment: could you try using `.moveToElement(svgElement, posX, posY).click().click().click().build().perform()`?

Comment: @santhoshkumar : actually there is a doubleclick() method with Actions class

Comment: yes.. I told like there is a double click but no triple click... Can you try Robot class?.....    Robot bot = new Robot();
    bot.mouseMove(element.getLocation().x,element.getLocation().x);
    bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
    bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

Comment: @santhoshkumar - I could consider the Robot class, but it seems overkill for this single edge case.

Comment: @Strike08  - It's my understanding that `perform` calls `build`. The only reason for call build is if you want to pass round a reference to the built object and/or call it multiple times. Is this not correct?

Comment: @DebanjanB - This project isn't hosted publicly anywhere at the moment. It's just a hobby project in its early stages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current api doesn't provide a way to simulate a triple click which would emit a single click event with the count of clicks.
So your best chance is likely to simulate the event with executeScript:

```
String JS_CLICK_TRIPLE = 
  "var target = arguments[0];                                 " +
  "var offsetX = arguments[1];                                " +
  "var offsetY = arguments[2];                                " + 
  "var rect = target.getBoundingClientRect();                 " +
  "var cx = rect.left + (offsetX || (rect.width / 2));        " +        
  "var cy = rect.top + (offsetY || (rect.height / 2));        " +
  "                                                           " +
  "emit('mousedown', {clientX: cx, clientY: cy, buttons: 1}); " +
  "emit('mouseup',   {clientX: cx, clientY: cy});             " +
  "emit('mousedown', {clientX: cx, clientY: cy, buttons: 1}); " +
  "emit('mouseup',   {clientX: cx, clientY: cy});             " +
  "emit('mousedown', {clientX: cx, clientY: cy, buttons: 1}); " +
  "emit('mouseup',   {clientX: cx, clientY: cy});             " +
  "emit('click',     {clientX: cx, clientY: cy, detail: 3});  " +
  "                                                           " +
  "function emit(name, init) {                                " +
    "target.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(name, init));        " +
  "}                                                          " ;


Actions action1 = new Actions(driver);
action1.moveToElement(yourElement, posX, posY).perform();

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
    JS_CLICK_TRIPLE, yourElement, posX, posY);
```

Comment: Hey it's been a while since you posted this, but can you translate this for python?

Comment: Help please...?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like below:

```
WebElement yourElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath locator here"));

Actions action = new Actions(driver);
Actions action1= new Actions(driver);
action1= action.moveToElement(yourElement).doubleClick();

action1.click().build().perform();
```

Comment: My understanding is that `Actions` are implemented using the builder pattern. Thus each method call on an instance - except `build` and `perform` - returns a new instance. Thus the above is equivalent to `new Actions(driver).moveToElement(yourElement).doubleClick().click().perform()`. With reference to the code in my question, this will cause `singleClickHandler` and `doubleClickHandler` to be called, but not `tripleClickHandler`.

Comment: @agdd : you are probably right; it was just a wild guess that chaining actions in this way might work

Answer (score 0):

you can also made a triple click like this:

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
for _ in range(3):
    actions.move_to_element(field).click()
actions.perform()
```

or even like this:

```
action1 = ActionChains(self.driver)
action1.move_to_element(field).click().click().click().perform()
```