# how do i triple-click on selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is there anyway to triple click to select a paragraph? I tried using doublclick and then click but it doesnt work.

```
actions.double_click()
actions.click()
```

Comment: Have you tried `actions.click();actions.click();actions.click()`?

Comment: Do you get a chance to look at this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330194/triple-click-using-selenium

Comment: Yes i looked at it but its for java. Can you translate it to python?

Comment: Someone? Please

Comment: You just have to use `driver.execute_script` instead of `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript` and adjust the rest of the script based on python.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330194/triple-click-using-selenium This link will help you to resolve